# how to add dimensions to a numpy element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a numpy.array like this

```
[[1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
 [7,8,9]]
```

How can i change it to this:-

```
[[[1,0], [2,0], [3,0]]
 [[4,0], [5,0], [6,0]]
 [[7,0], [8,0], [9,0]]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't without copying data or using dtype tricks. You can `np.stack((a, np.zeros_like(a)), -1)` if you are fine with copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `a` as the input array, you can use `array-assignment` and this would work for a generic `n-dim` input -

```
out = np.zeros(a.shape+(2,),dtype=a.dtype)
out[...,0] = a
```

Sample run -

```
In [81]: a
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [82]: out = np.zeros(a.shape+(2,),dtype=a.dtype)
    ...: out[...,0] = a

In [83]: out
Out[83]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0]],

       [[4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0]],

       [[7, 0],
        [8, 0],
        [9, 0]]])
```

If you play around with `broadcasting`, here's a compact one  -

```
a[...,None]*[1,0]
```

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot. Can you help this poor guy understand how it works? I'm totally lost. I understand the first line that it is create a dataframe with (3,3,2) shape of zeroes in it, the 2nd line is total magic to me.

Comment: @lionel319 Well it creates a (3,3,2) shaped array rather and the second line is basically : `out[:,:,0] = a`, i.e. indexing into the first column, while selecting all elements along first two axes and assigning `a` there. This should help out if you need further details - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Answer (score 2):

I think numpy.dstack might provide the solution. Let's call A your first array. Do

```
B = np.zeros((3,3))
R = np.dstack((A,B))
```

And R should be the array you want.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is unsigned integer and your dtype is "large enough", you can use the following code to pad zero without creating copy:

```
b = str(a.dtype).split('int')
b = a[...,None].view(b[0]+'int'+str(int(b[1])//2))
```

with `a` equal to your example, the output looks like

```
array([[[1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 0]],

       [[4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0]],

       [[7, 0],
        [8, 0],
        [9, 0]]], dtype=int16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This one is fast (for large operands), but pretty unsound. Also it only works for 32 or 64 bit dtypes. Do not use in serious code.

```
def squeeze_in_zero(a):
    sh = a.shape
    n = a.dtype.itemsize
    return a.view(f'f{n}').astype(f'c{2*n}').view(a.dtype).reshape(*a.shape, 2)
```

Speedwise at 10000 elements on my machine it is roughly on par with @Divakar's array assignment. Below it is slower, above it is faster.

Sample run:

```
>>> a = np.arange(-4, 5).reshape(3, 3)
>>> squeeze_in_zero(a)
array([[[-4,  0],
        [-3,  0],
        [-2,  0]],

       [[-1,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 1,  0]],

       [[ 2,  0],
        [ 3,  0],
        [ 4,  0]]])
```